# Skillbuilders save before exit

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex

I am using the Skillsbuilders Save Before Exit Oracle ApEx plugin within one of my pages but for some reason, I do not want it to fire when the user presses the "Save" button on the page that basically branches back to itself, when they change something on the page.

Now the "Save" button is fired as part of a Dynamic Action, which basically first calls a JavaScript function, followed by PL/SQL and then performs a apex.submit("SUBMIT") JavaScript call.

With this plugin, how can I prevent it from firing when the user presses the "Save" button because when a user changes a field on the screen and then proceeds to press the "Save" button, this plugin fires and displays the dialog to the user that changes have been made, which is not what I want. I just want it to save the changes and stay on the page.

See here for plugin details:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=46685:SAVE_BEFORE_EXIT:0:::::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read documentation http://skillbuilders.com/download/download-resource.cfm/instructions.pdf?file=Oracle-Apex/plugins/save_before_exit//instructions.pdf
You must change attribute of the plugin named "Disable Warning Selector". Specify jquery selector, applied for all buttons which you want to fire the dialog.